# Currency reverts back when user is selecting it from the dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am wanting to change my currency but its not setting the dropdown on reaload of the page the cookie is getting create ok but I want it to remember the value selected by the user.

```
@if (Model.AvailableCurrencies.Count > 1)
{

  var returnUrl = webHelper.GetRawUrl(Context.Request);
  var currencies = Model.AvailableCurrencies.Select(x => new 
   SelectListItem
   {
    Text = x.Name,
    Value =x.DisplayLocale,// //Url.RouteUrl("ChangeCurrency", new { 
    customercurrency = x.Id, returnUrl }, 
     webHelper.GetCurrentRequestProtocol()),
    Selected = x.Id.Equals(Model.CurrentCurrencyId)
}).ToList();

<form id="SetCurrency"
      asp-controller="Warehouse"
      asp-action="SetCurrency"
      asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
      method="post"
      class="form-horizontal nav-link text-dark"
      role="form">
    <select id="customerCurrency"
            asp-for="@Model.DisplayLocale"                
            name="customerCurrency" asp-items="@currencies"                
            onchange="this.form.submit();"></select>
    </form>
}
```

I need some way once its set to the cookie here it would read that value then set it in the list above.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult SetCurrency(string currencyName,string returnUrl)
 {
    string storeLocale = currencyName;
    var record = _context.Currencies.Where(w => w.DisplayLocale == 
    storeLocale).FirstOrDefault();
   
     if (record != null)
     {
            Response.Cookies.Append(
           "Cella.Locale",
          record.DisplayLocale,
           new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });
      }
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

The value is being set ok but as u see it reverts back to British the default currency

[image]
]

This is the data I am working with

[image]

Comment: You save chosen locale, it's ok, but value of a select tag is defined actually in server-side: `Selected = x.Id.Equals(Model.CurrentCurrencyId)`. There are two ways to resolve: persist 
state (CurrentCurrenctyId) on external storage (db) for every customer. Or add clientside  script, which will set right option value from a cookie, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ryan said all that I had to do was simply attach isSelected in my view model I was not doing that before and was silly that I didnt so what i did was where i set the currency was.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetCurrency(IFormCollection forms,string returnUrl)
{
   string storeLocale = forms["customerCurrency"].ToString();
   var record = _context.Currencies.Where(w => w.DisplayLocale == storeLocale)
   .FirstOrDefault();

    var currentLanguageId = _context.Appsettings.Where(w => w.Key == 
        Constants.FrontEndDefaultLanguageId).FirstOrDefault();
    currentLanguageId.Value = record.Id.ToString();
    _context.SaveChanges();
   if (record != null)
    {
    _toast.AddAlertToastMessage("Currecy changed to " + record.Name);
   
       _config[Constants.FrontEndDefaultLanguageId] = record.Id.ToString();
        Response.Cookies.Append(
        "Cella.Locale",
         storeLocale,
           new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });
     }
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```